# How to insert 'SizedBox' widgets in the list of 'FaIcon' widgets?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create a widget which replaces string of numbers into a row of correlated icons. That much is working great. But I want to have some gap between those icons. I am trying to use 'SizedBox' to achieve it. But I get an error - **"type 'SizedBox' is not a subtype of type 'FaIcon' of 'element'"**. What's happening here?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';

class NumberIcons extends StatelessWidget {
  const NumberIcons({
    super.key,
    required this.numberString,
    required this.color,
    this.size = 12,
    this.gap = 1,
  });

  final String numberString;
  final Color color;
  final double size;
  final double gap;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Map<String, IconData> iconsMap = {
      '1': FontAwesomeIcons.one,
      '2': FontAwesomeIcons.two,
      '3': FontAwesomeIcons.three,
      '4': FontAwesomeIcons.four,
      '5': FontAwesomeIcons.five,
      '6': FontAwesomeIcons.six,
      '7': FontAwesomeIcons.seven,
      '8': FontAwesomeIcons.eight,
      '9': FontAwesomeIcons.nine,
      '0': FontAwesomeIcons.zero,
    };

    List<Widget> iconsList = numberString
        .split('')
        .map(
          (digitString) => FaIcon(
            iconsMap[digitString]!,
            color: color,
            size: size,
          ),
        )
        .toList();

    iconsList;

    for (int i = iconsList.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      iconsList.insert(i, SizedBox(width: gap)); // this line is responsible for the error
    }

    return Row(
      children: iconsList,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though you type annotated `iconsList` with `List<Widget>`, the assigned list on the right-hand side is a `List<FaIcon>` at runtime. You should specify the generic type to the `map` method:

```dart
List<Widget> iconsList = numberString
    .split('')
    .map<Widget>( // Change this line
      (digitString) => FaIcon(
        iconsMap[digitString]!,
        color: color,
        size: size,
      ),
    )
    .toList();
```

---

Alternatively, you can use `SeparatedRow` from package [flextras](https://pub.dev/packages/flextras) to achieve that.

```dart
SeparatedRow(
  separatorBuilder: () => SizedBox(width: gap),
  children: iconsList,
)
```

Comment: You're welcome! By the way, I recommend using package [flextras](https://pub.dev/packages/flextras) to build a Row with gaps, if you don't mind using packages.